# Put Duplicates under Common Element JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code.Now I am building the list using Jquery. How do I do this using Javascript/JQuery?

Html(raw)after completion should look like this

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div>
          <ul id="listOne">
            <li class="columnItem">John</li><!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
            <li class="columnItem">James</li>
            <li class="columnItem">Mary</li><!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
          </ul>

          <ul id="listTwo">
            <li class="columnItem">John</li><!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
            <li class="columnItem">Mark</li>
            <li class="columnItem">Mary</li><!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
          </ul>
          <ul id="CommonLister">
            <li class="columnItem">John</li>
            <li class="columnItem">Mark</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Jquery/JavaScrpit

```
function myFunctioner(){
                $(() => {
                    let names = [];
                    let nameSet = new Set();

                    $("li.columnItemer").each((idx, ele) => {
                        nameSet.add($(ele).html())
                    });

                    var $common = $("<ul>").addClass("commmonLister");
                    nameSet.forEach((name) => {
                        if ($("li:contains(" + name + ")").length > 1) {
                            $("li:contains(" + name + ")").remove();
                            $("<li>").addClass("columnItemer").html(name).appendTo($common);
                        }
                    });
                    $common.appendTo($(".CommonLister"));
                });
            }
```

The above code only works if the list already exists on HTML not when dynamically creating the list. I will be building the list by Ajax query. really appreciate in if you guys can show me how to implement the above code dynamically as the list is built on click event.

Comment: the function that is populating `nameSet` happens on page load, I would suggest you functionise the code you have here and execute it again once you've ajaxed in your list items

Comment: Sorry I am new to Jquery could you guide me through.

Comment: is the intention to have a single list of `columnItems` under `#CommonLister` or to have a set of lists? (currently your code will create `ul`s under the `ul` with id `#CommonLister`) PS. your code is also trying to append this new `ul` to an element with _class_ of `CommonLister` not _id_ as it should

Comment: yes the intention is to have a single list of columnItems under #CommonLister

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've got. I don't use the new Javascript notation (not really a fan of it), though I'm sure you could transcribe what I've written into ES if you want to keep it consistent in your project.

I took a very similar approach to you, however I did not dynamically create the element. If you know this element will exist on the page anyway, my personal philosophy is just let it exist there and be empty so that you don't have to create it on your own.

If these lists are being loaded dynamically (something I couldn't really test out while using codepen) then put this into a function called after the list elements have been created. *Preferably you would simply go through the data when it is loaded and make the applicable DOM changes only once, but sometimes we do what we must*

```js
$(function() {
  $('#run-code').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //What were you doing? nope.
    var currentItems = {}; //Blank object
    var $mergeColumn = $('#CommonLister'); //Common list reference
    $('.columnItem').each(function(i, el) {
      var $el = $(el); //Notation I use to differentiate between the regular HTML Element and jQuery element
      if (!currentItems.hasOwnProperty($el.html())) {
        //Has this name come up before? if not, create it.
        currentItems[$el.html()] = []; //Make it equal to a brand spanking new array
      }
      currentItems[$el.html()].push(el);
      //Add the item to the array
    });

    $.each(currentItems, function(name, data) {
      //Loop through each name. We don't actually use the name variable because we don't care what someone's name is
      if (data.length > 1) {
        //Do we have more than 1 element in our array? time to move some stuff
        $.each(data, function(i, el) {
          var $el = $(el); //See note above
          if (i == 0) {
            //If this is the first element, let's just go ahead and move it to the merge column ul
            $el.appendTo($mergeColumn);
          } else {
            $el.remove(); //Otherwise, we've already got this element so delete this one.
          } //end if/else
        }); //end $.each(data)
      } //end if data.length >1
    }); //end $.each(currentItems)

  }); //end $.on()
}); //end $()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="run-code" class="btn btn-success">Click Me</button>

<h4>List 1</h4>
<ul id="listOne">
  <li class="columnItem">John</li>
  <!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
  <li class="columnItem">James</li>
  <li class="columnItem">Mary</li>
  <!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
</ul>
<h4>List 2</h4>
<ul id="listTwo">
  <li class="columnItem">John</li>
  <!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
  <li class="columnItem">Mark</li>
  <li class="columnItem">Mary</li>
  <!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
</ul>
<h4>Common List</h4>
<ul id="CommonLister">
</ul>
```